uniform converge of $\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}$
considering the function:
$\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}$
in the interval (0,1) it converges pointwise to 0, I want to prove that the it doesn't corverge uniformly.
I was going to use the definition of uniform convergence:
$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N} : \forall x \in X , \forall n≥N |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $
I thought that for x close to 0, the function is close to 1, so no matter how big n is there will always be some f(x) outside of (0,$\epsilon$).
Is this proof enough? I also would not know why other functions like $\frac{\sin((\sqrt n) x)}{nx}$ or $\frac{\sin(nx^2)}{nx}$, that also converge pointwise in the same interval, instead do converge uniformly

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

For the first one take $x=\frac 1 n$; for the other two just note that $|\sin t |\leq |t|$.

@JoséCarlosSantos edited I hope it's ok now

@geetha290krm that doesn't really help me for uniform convergence I think (?)

MathJax tips: \sin t -> $\sin t$ looks better than $sin(t)$. f_n -> $f_n$.

This post is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318253, found using Approach$0$ https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(nx)%7D%7Bnx%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3AUniform&p=1
